# Libvirt in Qt error while compiling in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, libvirt

Why is it that i get this error

```
error: undefined reference to `virConnectOpen'
```

whenever I compile it and many other functions too?

After some research I found this:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.emulators.libvirt/62812
but I don't know how to include that `-lvirt` option for *gcc* in Qt Creator.

Comment: did you try http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a *qmake* project, open the `.pro` file, and this line to include that library:

```
LIBS += -lvirt
```

---

Also, you can look at the actual *gcc* compile commands in the Compile Output view, which you can select from the bottom of the screen. After adding that, you should see `-lvirt` added to the link command (last `gcc` or `g++` command in the output). It's useful to learn how to look at that output, when solving problems like this, where you need to get some options added for the compiler or linker, and want to see what options are actually given to it.